# Where are the user/config files for Ridiculous Fishing?

Tags: android, ridiculous-fishing

After having made significant progress with Ridiculous Fishing, I would like to backup or transfer to another Android device.

The following directories were created on my device, but there are no files there:

```
/Android/data/com.vlambeer.RidiculousFishing.humble/cache
/Android/obb/com.vlambeer.RidiculousFishing.humble
```

Is there any way to backup or transfer the configuration files for this game?

Comment: There are no files, or you can't see any files?

Comment: This question did occur to me, but I've already poked around, and there are no hidden or system files visible. The device is a 1st gen Pixel, so I am connecting to a computer via MTP. Naturally, MTP controls what is visible, but I can see user data for (some) other games on this device. If you can suggest other ways to interact with the file system, I am all for it.